# This function is called multiple times in jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to get some data and pass it to viewModel but the forEach loop is called mutiple times only when the viewModel method is called otherwise its called once as it should can you help me out where the problem is in my code:

my Screen

```
   Column(Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {

        Text(text = "Upload ScreenView")

        GetMainContent { mainContents ->
            Log.i(TAG,"MainContents is getting twice is doubt $mainContents")
            mainContents.forEach { mainContent ->

                if(mainContent.contentType == "Products"){
                    Log.i(TAG, "If Main Contents again is repeating $mainContent")
                   viewModel.gettingTheProductContents(mainContent.contentTags)
                }

            }
```

if i get rid of the viewModel call its working fine only when is this called its getting rendered multiple times

MyLog if you see first is when viewModel is called twice log appears and then when uncommented its called once:

```
 I  MainContents is getting twice is doubt [MainContent(contentId=2C0dLLFto893vRLdQrmV, contentPosition=1,
  I  MainContents is getting twice is doubt [MainContent(contentId=2C0dLLFto893vRLdQrmV, contentPosition=1,


 for package com.shivaconsulting.zipzipadmin ----------------------------
 ---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (29382) for package com.shivaconsulting.zipzipadmin ----------------------------
 2023-08-01 14:06:23.303 29382-29382 AppTag                  com.shivaconsulting.zipzipadmin      I  MainContents is getting twice is doubt [MainContent(contentId=2C0dLLFto893vRLdQrmV,
```

My viewModel method call:

```
     fun gettingTheProductContents(mainContentTags: List<String>?){

     viewModelScope.launch {
         if (mainContentTags != null) {
             useCases.getProductsContent(mainContentTags).collect{
                 getProductsContentResponse = it
             }
         }
     }
```

MyCompose Getting data from Firestore:

```
@Composable
fun GetMainContent(
viewModel: MainContentUploadViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
getMainContent: @Composable (mainContents : MainContents) -> Unit
){
when(val mainContentResponse = viewModel.getMainContentDataResponse){
    is Response.Success -> getMainContent(mainContentResponse.data!!)
    else -> {

    }
}
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Actually we shouldn't be doing such operations (calling viewModel methods) inside Composables, for that we have `SideEffects`. Can you try the below approach.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun GetMainContent(
  viewModel: MainContentUploadViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
){
  // by passing Unit this method is called only once
  // if you want that to be called multiple times, say on some variable change, you should use a different key
  // like, declare a variable
  // val refresh by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
  // update the value of refresh by your UI, such as on a button click and use it as 
  // LaunchedEffect(refresh) { ... }
  LaunchedEffect(Unit) { 
     viewModel.getMainContent()
  }

  // ... all your UI here
  Column { 
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't query your ViewModel like this inside a Composable. There are 2 ways to do that right: Either you will use [`SideEffects`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect) or [`states`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state-hoisting#viewmodels-as-state-owner) and use the `. collectAsStateWithLifecycle()` function in your Composable to get your ViewModel data.